# Elasticsearch query not returning results when querying by email

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

In an elasticsearch index, I have a field called `reporter`, and I get no results when I run this query:

```
GET /index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "reporter": "Andr" } }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However, I get many results if I change the value to the full first name of "Andre". How can I return records where the `reporter` field contains "A", "An", "And", "Andr", etc.? I only ever get results when the value matches a full string between periods in the email.

Here are the analysis settings:

```
{
   "analysis": {
      "filter": {
         "email": {
            "type": "pattern_capture",
            "preserve_original": true,
            "patterns": [
               "([^@]+)",
               "(\\p{L}+)",
               "(\\d+)",
               "@(.+)",
               "([^-@]+)"
            ]
         }
      },
      "analyzer": {
         "email": {
            "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",
            "filter": [
               "email",
               "lowercase",
               "unique"
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And here's the `reporter` mapping:

```
"reporter": {
    "type": "text",
    "analyzer": "email"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edge N-gram filter can help to solve your use case. It basically outputs n-grams from the beginning of the token. The n grams can be controlled by setting the min_gram and max_gram fields. We can use the below filter setting to output as required for your example outlined above.

```
"filter": [
    { "type": "edge_ngram",
      "min_gram": 1
    }
  ]
```

More details can be found in this link

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenfilter.html

Comment: So I would use that filter instead of the email filter? Or in addition to it?

Comment: depends on your use case. but it should work on both cases